# Python will not import a function from a file in a weird file structure | Python 3.10

Tags: python

This is my file structure:
[image]

I am trying to get a function (getFreq()) out of the utils.py file.

However, when doing this in the part1.py file:

```py
from ..utils.utils import getFreq

print(getFreq(["R8","U5","L5","D3"]))
```

It just says: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

How would I fix this and import it?

Note: the `__init__.py` file is empty in the `utils` folder to make Python think it is a module (What I have been told to do on Google).

Comment: Does the parent directory of `day3` (presumably  `2021`) have an `__init__.py`, so it is considered as a Python module?

Comment: Think so - at least that is what google have said :)

Comment: When I look at your screenshot I am under the impression that there is only a `.gitignore` but no `__init__.py` inside the `2021` directory.

Comment: Hmm, will that fix it?

Comment: No, it doesn't fix it...

Comment: This is asked constantly, and `__init__.py` files [aren't relevant to this particular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for). The problem is that when you tell Python to run `part1.py` directly, it has, per the rules, no reason to treat the `2021` folder as a package root. The leading `.`s don't traverse the folder hierarchy on disk (after all, there are other ways to import a module than reading a .py file!); they traverse a *package* hierarchy. Please see the duplicates I linked for details.

Comment: That said, you are still going to run into problems, because the implied, fully-qualified name of your module within its package is `2021.day3.part1`, which is not a valid identifier. You will want to rename your `2021` folder.